# Using migrate, how can you set the default format to Full HTML?

Tags: importing-exporting, theming

Using the migrate module to import content from a database. One of the fields contains full HTML but on import the text field defaults to plain text. The admin default is set to Full HTML, but even though the imports are being created by admin, it defaults to plain text.

How do you set the default to full HTML for imports? There's obviously a way around this in code but wondering if there's a patch or anyone has advice on the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 6, when you import with the Migrate and Table Wizard modules there is a text field when mapping each field that is empty. Just type in full_html and each node when imported with have full_html entered into that row in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->addFieldMapping('body', 'body')
     ->arguments(array('format' => 'full_html'));
```

This works for me.

Comment: Does it work for comments as well?